# Unity - Interception instance handling

Tags: c#, unity-container

How do I modify the way Interception Behavior instances are handled?

What I do is:
- regster a type with a singleton lifetime
- add interface based interception
- add a custom Interception Behavior

Now, every time i resolve the type the instance is the same. BUT the Interception Behavior is recreated. Also comparing instances with Equals will fail.

Here is what I got:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <sectionExtension type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.Configuration.InterceptionConfigurationExtension, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.Configuration" />
  <container>
    <extension type="Interception" />
    <register type="MyInterfaces.IMyItf, MyInterfaces" mapTo="MyLib.Impl1, MyLib">
      <lifetime type="singleton" />
      <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor"/>
      <interceptionBehavior type="MyInterceptionBehavior, MyUnityExt" />
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```

So I either need a singleton instance (or one instance per resolved singleton) of **MyInterceptionBehavior**.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

To register a singleton CallHandler, you need to pass to it a ContainerControlledLifetimeManager instance when registering, as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<TestHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.AddNewExtension<Interception>().AddCallHandler(container.Resolve<TestHandler>());
```

**Edit**

Via app.config:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<alias alias="IExample" type="LifetimeManagement.IExample, LifetimeManagement" />
<alias alias="Example" type="LifetimeManagement.Example, LifetimeManagement" />
<container name="container">
   <extension type="Interception" />
   <interceptor type="InterfaceInterceptor" />     <register type="IHandler" mapTo="MyTestHandler">
    <lifetime type="singleton" />
  </register>
</container>
```

Comment: How do I achive this using the app.config?

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. I edited my post with more details. please take a look.